# Retrieve Parent record field values using Query API

Tags: rest-api, api, query, metadata-api

I am trying to query Salesforce opportunities from another Salesforce org using the Query API

I am setting the following query in the endpoint method

```
request.setEndpoint('callout:'+namedCredential+'/services/data/v56.0/query?q=select+Id,+Name,+Amount+from+Opportunity+where+Brand__c+in+('+brandIdString+')');
```

Now, the above query works fine and returns all the required Opportunities.

However, now what happens is that if I try to add any relational field in the query, it fails. e.g. the below request fails

```
request.setEndpoint('callout:'+namedCredential+'/services/data/v56.0/query?q=select+Id,+Name,+Amount,+Brand__r.Address__c+from+Opportunity+where+Brand__c+in+('+brandIdString+')');
```

Is the above not possible? If not are there any alternatives for the same?

I am getting the following message in the debug log [image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the error message.

Comment: it looks like you are missing a comma between Amount and Brand__r

Comment: @DanielHoechst, actually I have the comma in my code. It was a miss while posting.

Comment: If no error, by any chance are you using `system.debug(results)` to display the resulting values? if so, system.debug will not display parent field values of sobjects.  The values are there, but must be explicitly enumerated in a debug statement

Comment: @cropredy I have added the error message that \i am getting in the debug log

Comment: this should work fine, I did an equivalent in workbench - the error says you have a duplicate column - in what you posted, was that the exact query or did you excerpt it for clarity?